# Как сделать на один компонент несколько роутов и чтобы лишний раз они не перерисовывались, Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

Набросал пример, код так себе но суть в следующем.
Есть ChildComponent он отображает реактивную форму, которая в последствии может быть заполнена.
После заполнения формы и сохранении ее она закидывается в общий стейт и автоматически должен меняться роут добавляя id к текущему пути. На данный момент при сохранении у нас полностью пересоздается компонент и происходит еле заметное моргание экрана, но если добавить в будущем запрос на сервер то моргание усилится. Как избавиться от такого эффекта и в случае сохранения не перерисовывать компонент, а менять по факту только роут или возможно есть способ просто не перерисовывать один и тот же компонент.
Так же при переходе на роут с неправильным id у нас компонент рендериться 2 раза, хотя по идее просто должна сбрасываться формы и у роута пропадает id

Рутовый модуль Роутинга

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./root/parent.module').then(m => m.ParentModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'child',
    loadChildren: () => import('./child/child.module').then(m => m.ChildModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Чилдрен модуль Роутинга

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {ChildComponent} from "./child.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ChildComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ChildComponent
  }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class ChildRoutingModule {
}
```

Стейт

```
export interface Card {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string
}

export const STATE: Card[] = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'First',
    description: 'First'
  }, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Second',
    description: 'Second'
  }
]
```

Верстка Чилдрен компонента

```
<a routerLink="/">to Root</a>
<div *ngFor="let item of STATE">
  <a [routerLink]="'/child/' + item.id">to {{ item.name }}</a>
</div>
<form
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
  [formGroup]="formGroup"
  style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 200px"
>
  <label>Name:
    <input style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box"
           formControlName="name">
  </label>

  <label>Description:
    <textarea style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; resize: none"
              formControlName="description"></textarea>
  </label>

  <button style="width: 100%" type="submit" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Сам Чилдрен компонент

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {STATE} from "../state";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrl: './child.component.css'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  readonly STATE = STATE;
  formGroup: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    description: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit')
    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']
    if (id) {
      const item = STATE.find(el => el.id === id)
      if (item) this.formGroup.patchValue(item)
      else this.router.navigate(['..'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute})
    } else {
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('ngOnDestroy')
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']
    if (id) {
      const itemIndex = STATE.findIndex(el => el.id === id)
      if (itemIndex) {
        STATE[itemIndex].id = id.toString()
        STATE[itemIndex].name = this.formGroup.value.name
        STATE[itemIndex].description = this.formGroup.value.description
      }
    } else {
      const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)
      STATE.push({
        id: random.toString(),
        name: this.formGroup.value.name,
        description: this.formGroup.value.description
      })

      this.router.navigate(['./', random], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute})
    }
  }
}
```